# Determine offset using only bitmask

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Hello' I've got a problem

there is some telemetry values packed in words (or double words) and bitmask for each telemetry channel.

for example i've got mask 0xf000 and word value 0x2499

after & operation i've got 0x2000,but real telemetry value packed in this word is 0x2 (0x2000>>12). How can i determine this offset using only mask and without cycles like:

```
offset = 0;
for (int i = 0;i<32 i++)
{
    if ((mask>>i)&1)
        {
        offset = i
        break;
        }
}
```

Comment: How is mask itself being calculated and/or assigned?

Comment: mask is setted in configuration of telemetry parameter

Comment: Do have the control to added parameters to this configuration?

Comment: yes. i can add another field like "offset", but want to try find another way

Comment: Is the mask always 0×f aligned on 4 bit bounderies

Comment: check this http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightFloatCast

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use some built in functions to get the first non-zero bit index.For example GCC has `int __builtin_ffs (int x)`

```
— Built-in Function: int __builtin_ffs (int x)
Returns one plus the index of the least significant 1-bit of x, or if x is zero, returns zero.
```

So in your case:

```
offset = __builtin_ffs(mask);
```

MSDN has similar intrinsics `_BitScanForward` and `_BitScanForward64`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfd9z0bb.aspx

All these builtin functions use special assembly instruction which performs the required calculation on the hardware level.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look at intrinsics to perform a "scan". The instruction "int _bit_scan_forward(int)" should do the trick ;)

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#cats=Bit%20Manipulation